# Como aplicar un tema a mi spinner mediante codigo

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual se crea un spinner, quiero aplicarle un estilo, pero no tienen ningún cambio a momento de ejecutar la aplicación, lo estoy haciendo mal? estoy dejando pasar algo y no me doy cuenta? o es imposible aplicarle un estilo desde código a este widget?

Código Style:

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearanceSpinnerItem</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearanceSpinnerItem" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/coloarAzulClaro</item>
</style>
```

Código para crear spinner:

```
public void createSpinner(List<FormatoEnum> enumList) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(0, dpToPx(20), 0, 0);
    AppCompatSpinner spinner = new AppCompatSpinner(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.SpinnerTheme));
    spinner.setId(id());
    SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(context, enumList);
    spinner.setLayoutParams(lp);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    bodyLayout.addView(spinner);
}
```

Comment: Según esta respuesta dice que no se puede porque el estilo se debe poner antes que la vista sea creada, puedes revisar la respuesta   [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482742/how-to-set-style-for-spinner-programmatically)